# JQM - Inject dynamic content at load time only

Tags: jquery-mobile

I'm trying to dynamically populate a select tag at load time (latest jQM version) using a custom template filling function.

If the fn is called in the "pagebeforechange" event, the select tag is properly initialized. Since this event is called on every page transition, I thought of moving the fn to the 'pageinit' event. This does not work, presumably because the DOM is not yet fully available. How can I coerce jQM to inject content in a page only once? Currently, I am using a kludge. There surely must be a smarter way. Thanks for any suggestions.

```
  $(document).bind('pageinit', function () {
     InitSelTagTest("#selActTag", "tplTag"); // Does not work.
  });

  $(document).bind("pagebeforechange", function (e, data) {        
     if ($("#selActTag").children().size() === 0) {
        InitSelTagTest("#selActTag", "tplTag"); // Kludge, but it works
     }
  });

  function InitSelTagTest(el,tpl) { // Append all tags to element el      
     var lstAllTags = JSON.parse($("#hidTag").val()); // Create tag array

     // Retrieve html content from template.
     var cbeg = "//<![" + "CDATA[", cend = "//]" + "]>";
     var rslt = tmpl(tpl, { ddd: lstAllTags }).replace(cbeg, ").replace(cend,");            

     $(el).html(rslt).trigger("create"); // Add to DOM.
  }
```

**EDIT**
In response to Shenaniganz' comment, it seems that the "pagebeforecreate" event could do the trick ie.

```
$("#pgAct").live("pagebeforecreate", function () {
    // Populate tag select. Works. Traversed only once.      
    InitSelTag("#selActTag", "tplTag"); 
});
```

Comment: Probably not what your looking for but you could just set a flag.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I fully understand your question but I'll throw a few things out there and you let me know if I can extend further.

To make something trigger only once on page load you can try to implement a regular JQuery `$(document).ready(function(){})` aka `$(function(){})` for the exact reason why JQuery Mobile users are told not to use it. It triggers only once on DOM load. Further pages don't trigger it because they're being switched via Ajax.

Other than that, on regular dynamic content loading you take a look at the following example I put together for someone else earlier:

http://jsbin.com/ozejif/1/edit

Comment: Thanks. I tried this approach: the dynamic content is added to the DOM, but it remains hidden even if a trigger("create") or page() method are used. Not sure, but it seems the "pagebeforecreate" event may come to the rescue here (see Edit in my original post).

Comment: As pointed out above, $(document).ready() inserts dynamic content, but the html tags remain hidden. Tried to render them (make visible) via trigger("refresh/ create"), show(), etc. to no avail. In my case, "pagebeforecreate" seems to be the solution.

Comment: That's what I was referring to , your solution. If it works , go ahead and post it as a solution below.

Comment: I posted an outline on how to inject dynamic content [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12375988/jqm-debating-correct-approach-to-load-dynamic-content) for those who are interested.